# Reading from and Writing to a processes I/O?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, std

Suppose we have two programs, `A` and `B`. `B` prints something continuously and reads input too. (probably there are two processes in `B` using same I/O, I don't know if it is possible or not...)

`A` have to read `B`'s output and decide about what to say to `B`, then sends a string to `B`'s input. (just like that someone inputs text by keyboard to `B`).

I know that `B` uses `std::cout` to send messages to output and uses `std::cin` for read input.

How can I write `A` using C++ and standard library? Is this related to sockets or ipc?

Note: I'm using a i386 Linux system.

Comment: This is IPC and is highly OS dependent. What platform are you developing for?

Comment: @ RageD: I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 10.10).

Comment: Tagged with the important OS info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unofficial [boost Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) library, which has an [excellent tutorial](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html#process.tutorials.read_from_child) of exactly what you want to do and is bound to be an official part of boost any time now. It's also naturally cross-platform. HTH

Comment: Thank you, but I have to use only C++ standard library :-(

Comment: @Sorush: You cannot use only C++ standard library, because interprocess communication not part of C++. You will have to use OS API anyway, which the boost Process library has conveniently wrapped into nice C++ for you.

Comment: So what should i do now? Can I write my own ipc mechanism using std only?